# Wicket pageparameter

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to add and fetch with a key as `String` and value as `List<object>` in Wicket `PageParameters`.

While am fetching the value with key, I got `classcastException:String cant be converted into list.`

I am using something like this:

```
List<Example> list = (List<Example>)params.get("ExampleList");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version did you work with?

Comment: Can you show the code snippet corresponding to parameters populating ?

Answer (score 9):

You can't store objects in `PageParameters` because `PageParameters` are an abstraction of HTTP request parameters and the protocol only supports `String` values. You have to get the list of Strings from the parameters and process it into `Example` objects.

```
List<StringValue> values = parameters.getValues("examples");
for(StringValue value : values) {
    Example example = new Example(value.toString());
    examples.add(example);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand somethings in this comment. I think this line should be String values = parameters.get("examples"); as the parameter get method returns "string". That I cannot assign to a List. Even if I get String array from get() mthd, I cannot assign the string object as Example object instance. "Value.toString" may not be expected in Example class constructor. So I dont know if this solution will work. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: My example uses code for Wicket 1.5 where the API for `PageParameters` has changed.

Comment: Ok.That makes sense.I am using wicket 1.4.9. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Populate PageParameters
final String dynamicValue = textFieldID.getModelObject();       
PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
pageParameters.add("username", usernameValue);  
pageParameters.add("username", "fixedValue");

// Retrieving PageParameters
String newValue = parameters.getValues("username").get(1).toString();
// here newValue will contain "fixedValue" (the second element)
```